# Using require(success) for a transaction call in a withdraw function, after emptying the callers saved amount of ether

Tags: solidity, security

In this contract:

```
contract auction {
address highestBidder;
uint highestBid;
mapping(address => uint) refunds;

function bid() payable external {
    require(msg.value >= highestBid);

    if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
        refunds[highestBidder] += highestBid; // record the refund that this user can claim
    }

    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    highestBid = msg.value;
}

function withdrawRefund() external {
    uint refund = refunds[msg.sender];
    refunds[msg.sender] = 0;
    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call.value(refund)("");
    require(success);
}

}
```

To write a safe withdrawal function, we need to first empty the refunds mapping for the `msg.sender`. Then we call `.value(refund)("")` to transfer the ether to `msg.sender`. After that, we check if the transfer was successful by writing `require(success)`.
my question is what if the transaction failed and `require(success)` doesn't pass? will the value of `refunds[msg.sender]` remain 0 and he can't withdraw again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transaction get fails all state changes will revert. So refunds[msg.sender] will be equal to what was it.

Comment: So you mean the whole function will execute only if all the require statements pass?

Comment: Thats how the EVM works yeah

Comment: You can read this article to learn more about it: https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e